# How to login into a Laravel app using cURL

Tags: laravel, curl

I want to setup a small file of `cURL` requests so I can quickly test my Laravel app's API quickly.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck at logging in :D.

This is what I have so far:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -d @./curl/user.json http://localhost:8000/login -o ./curl/response.json -v
```

I have a `user.json` file that has my login info:

```
{
    "email": "boss@example.com",
    "password": "password",
}
```

And I would like to output the data into my `response.json` file.

Nothing is working though. I have a poor understanding of a couple of these technologies. Anyone able to hold my hand through this?

With the `-v` tag, I'm getting:

```
 connect to ::1 port 8000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> POST /login HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 81
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
} [81 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Host: localhost:8000
< Date: Mon, 17 Jan 2022 01:47:53 GMT
< Connection: close
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.27
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< Date: Mon, 17 Jan 2022 01:47:53 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkpoUkhoQnNWdEVhYUdGU2wzckg5c3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidGwrUHpBcDV4Z2lXNWdObmQrdER2OUp0aEIveXhpdFNREmovedSomeSTufffForSecurityPurposesmNyb3oiLCJtYWMiOiIyZTY2Yzk1MWY3MDA3M2I3NDkzMmQzMTUwMjcyNDFmMTU3MTU
0MzRmZjAzNDBjZmZmZTgwMjg1MjMzOThkZmU5IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 17-Jan-2022 03:47:53 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax
<
```

Any idea how I can login to a Larvel app using cURL? The goal is to make it work like Postman, but in the terminal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to setup a small file of cURL requests so I can quickly test my Laravel app's API quickly.

> Any idea how I can login to a Larvel app using cURL? The goal is to make it work like Postman, but in the terminal!

Login using Laravel's default authentication page and API authentication are two different things. I can't explain to you about API authentication in depth, as it would be quite lengthy.

Laravel has two packages that you can use for this case, [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport) and [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum).

Sanctum is automatically installed when you install Laravel.

Since middleware on web is different from API, you should focus on route `routes/api.php`. You can create a token generation route (same as login). For example :

```
Route::post('/token', function (Request $request) {

    // You can replace it with your login logic
    $user = User::first();
    $token = $user->createToken('Your Awesome Token Name');

    return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken];

});
```

Return :

```
{
  "token": "1|jLw1HhWJhSVQq81VFZwhxYB93GKMl5JRCrtuYQ36"
}
```

Then, the generated token you can use to access other API routes.

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Calling via cURL :

```
curl -i http://your-awesome-app.test/api/user -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>"
```

Change `<TOKEN>` :

```
curl -i http://your-awesome-app.test/api/user -H "Authorization: Bearer 1|jLw1HhWJhSVQq81VFZwhxYB93GKMl5JRCrtuYQ36"
```

Viola!!!

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"Your Awesome User",
  "email":"your.awesome@user.test",
  "email_verified_at":"2022-01-17T03:03:58.000000Z",
  "created_at":"2022-01-17T03:03:58.000000Z",
  "updated_at":"2022-01-17T03:03:58.000000Z"
}
```